# How can you get a pre-image from the inverse if it's not defined?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, inverse

From Discrete Math [course notes on Inverse functions](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MATH_220_Discrete_Math/5%3A_Functions/5.5%3A_Inverse_Functions_and_Composition)

> If a function $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is many-to-one, then it does not have an inverse function. This makes the notation $g^{−1}(3)$ meaningless. Nonetheless, $g^{-1}(\{3\})$ is well-defined, because it means the preimage of {3}. If $g^{−1}(\{3\})=\{1,2,5\}$, we know $g(1) = g(2) = g(5) = 3$.

Why are we allowed to say $g^{-1}(D)$ where D is a set if $g^{-1}$ is undefined? Is this just a notational sleight of hand, where $g^{-1}$ is not taken to refer to an inverse function, but rather only to the domain of $g$, when you pass in a set? It seems nonsensical to pass a parameter in to a function that does not exist.

Or is $g^{-1}$ actually *defined* but not as a function, but rather as a relation?

Comment: As you point out, $g^{-1}$ can mean either inverse or preimage. The inverse doesn't have to be defined for the preimage to exist.

Comment: @John: It wouldn't mean "preimage" would it? It would mean "function that takes in a set an returns the associated preimage"?

Comment: You are overthinking this. The same notation can mean an inverse function or the definition of the set that contains all elements of the domain that get mapped to the same subset of the codomain.

Comment: Wiktionary incidentally has a definition which helped clear things up for me.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preimage#Noun I was drawing a false dichotomy because you take the "preimage of" the subset of the codomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mostly a notational sleight of hand, and a matter of definitions. Essentially, $g^{-1}$ is doing a lot of legwork here.

- When given a specified value and when $g$ is invertible, $g^{-1}(y)$ for that single value $y$ gives you the $x$ such that $g(x) = y$.
- Regardless of the invertibility, when we are dealing with a set $S$ (be it a singleton or otherwise), we define the symbol $g^{-1}(S)$ to be all elements of the domain which are sent into $S$ by $g$, i.e.
  $$g^{-1}(S) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ x \in \mathrm{domain}(g) \mid g(x) \in S \}$$
  Notice how this does not depend on invertibility. (If it is invertible, then $S$ will be the same size as the output set, loosely speaking.)

---

Be sure to notice a distinction: the first takes in and puts out values; the second takes in and puts out sets. Even when the function is invertible, in fact. Taking $g(x) = x^3$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as an example,

$$g^{-1}(8) = 2 \text{ whereas } g^{-1}(\{8\}) = \{2\}$$

Another example of note would be $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x = 0 \\
0 & x \ne 0
\end{cases}
$$
This function is not invertible (since, for instance, $g(2) = g(3) = 0$). Hence the notion of $g^{-1}(0)$ is undefined (as a single value). However, we can see that
$$
g^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \qquad
g^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{0\}
$$
because every real number except $0$ is sent to $0$, and $0$ itself is sent to $1$.

---

Consequently, whether it is intended for you to interpret $g^{-1}$ as a set or a value ultimately depends on the context, namely:

- Is $g$ invertible?
- More importantly, are you looking at a set or a single value?

Admittedly it is a bit of an overloaded notation and can cause some confusion, but I think interpreting the set case as a "generalization" of the value case makes that idea more evocative.

Comment: +1 It's worth also noting that some authors use [alternate notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image), to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: Thanks, this vibes well with what I just read on Wiktionary as well (see above).  Correct to say that $g^{-1}$ in this case is a Relation?  Also.. Is it fair to say that this version of $g^{-1}$ *always* exists if g exists?  Even if g is neither surjective nor injective?

Comment: Regarding the first question: my reasoning as to why it would be a Relation rather than a function would be that it outputs multiple values for one input.. I guess that hinges on whether you consider (1 input set -> 1 unique output set) to be a function or not

Comment: I guess the "preimage of" version of $g^{-1}$ is a multivalued function - producing unique sets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function